# Find the mean of a sub matrix if the first column of the matrix provides the index values

Tags: matlab, matrix, octave, mean

For a given matrix `Z` and assuming the first column refers to index values, is it possible to find the mean of `Z(:,2:3)` based on the index values in the first column `Z(:,1)`.

```
Z  =  [1    3    4
       2    7    8
       1    3    9
       3    4    4
       1    5    7]
```

So how can I loop over `Z` to find the mean of corresponding rows with index value 1 (in the first column) i.e finding the mean of `Z1`

```
Z1  =    3  4
         3  9
         5  7
```

Please can anyone help by explaining how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
mean(mean(Z(Z(:,1)==1,2:3)))
```

Comment: Thanks so much Ghaul! I actually managed to solve my problem without the second mean.

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
mean([accumarray(Z(:,1), Z(:,2),[],@mean), accumarray(Z(:,1), Z(:,3),[],@mean)]')'
```

It gives you the mean corresponding to each number. i.e. row one of the result is the mean for rows corresponding to `1`, row two is for `2` etc

Comment: Thanks for teaching me 'accumarray()', that's a pretty nice solution

Answer (score 2):

`Bsxfun` appproach -

```
Zc = [Z(:,1) mean(Z(:,[2 3]),2)]

ind1 = bsxfun(@eq,Zc(:,1),min(Zc(:,1)):max(Zc(:,1)))
mean_values = sum(bsxfun(@times,ind1,Zc(:,2)))./sum(ind1,1)
```

Output -

```
mean_values =
    5.1667    7.5000    4.0000
```

Answer (score 2):

To do that for every index in column 1, all at once:

```
>> accumarray(repmat(Z(:,1),size(Z,2)-1,1), reshape(Z(:,2:3),[],1), [], @mean)
ans =
    5.1667
    7.5000
    4.0000
```